# Linux command to get location of env file

Tags: linux

What command can I use to find out which file lists environment variables, as a user? It is not in ~/.bash_profile  or ~/.bashrc.

Thanks

Comment: for ubuntu based distros you can check also /etc/environment

Comment: Environoment variables can be set anywhere. Can you tell us which variable specifically you are searching for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532155/linux-where-are-environment-variables-stored - but to view use `printenv | less`

Comment: There is no such thing as a file that "lists environment variables". Please ask what you are looking for. Not, how you think that you might be able to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of these things are going to be dynamic.  You can get a look at the current environment by doing:

```
env | less
```

You can add environment variables into your session on bash startup by modifying `~/.bashrc` and placing variables at the end of the file.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/custom_path
export CUSTOM_ENV_VARIABLE=somevalue
```